# How to move a value in a 2D Array without creating a shift in the array in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, project, swap

So the thing is our school assigned us to code a board game called "parcheesi" and it's all okay but I cannot figure out how to move the pieces without shifting the whole board. You see, I created the board by creating an integer matrix and each integer is equal to something in the matrix(such as pieces, path, starting points and finish points. I figured it could be easier to assign a different value to the path blocks in the corner to change the direction. I know I could not really describe my situations so I will elaborate the situation in the comments. But here is a piece of my code(edited a little bit):

table:

```
    {8911,8912, 0  ,4,  1, 4, 0, 8211,8212},
    {0,8913, 0  ,1,8223,1, 0, 8214,8213},
    {0,   0,    0  ,1,8222,1, 0, 0,   0},
    {4,   8914,      1,4,8221,4, 1, 1,   4},
    {1,   8923,8922,8921,0,6621,6622,6623,1},
    {4,   1,   1,   4,7121,4, 1, 1,   4},
    {0,   0,   0,   1,7122,1, 0, 0,   0},
    {7111,7112,0,   1,7123,1, 0,  6611,6612},
    {7114,7113,0,   4, 1,  4, 0,  6614,6613}

  int pawnmove(int steps, int row, int col, int max, int matrix[max][max])/*This function helps me to move the pawns by swapping the respective characters in the matrix. 
4's in the matrix trigger the corner points so the pawns will redirect at those points*/
{
    int i=col;
    int l_move=steps;
    int j=row;
    int tmp;
    
    while(l_move>0)
    {
        if((row<4)&&((col>=0)&&(col<=3)))//since there are 4 area in the matrix, I divided the code into 4 pieces.
        {
            
            
            while((i<col+steps)&&(matrix[row][i]!=4)&&((row==3)||(row==0)))
            {
                i+=1;
            } 
            tmp=matrix[row][i];
            matrix[row][i]=matrix[row][col];
            matrix[row][col]=tmp;
            
            l_move=steps-(i-col);
            
            if((l_move)>0)
            {
                while(((row-j)< l_move)&&(matrix[j][i]!=4))
                {
                    j-=1;
                }
                printf("%d", j);
                tmp=matrix[j][i];
                matrix[j][i]=matrix[row][i];
                matrix[row][i]=4;
                if(col==i)
                {
                    matrix[row][i]=1;
                }
                l_move=l_move-(row-j);
            
            
            }   
        
        }

        else if((row>=4)&&((col>=0)||(col<3)))//since there are 4 area in the matrix, I divided the code into 4 pieces.
        {
            
            while((i<col+steps)&&(matrix[row][i]!=4)&&((row==3)))
            {
                i+=1;
            }
            tmp=matrix[row][i];
            matrix[row][i]=matrix[row][col];
            matrix[row][col]=tmp;
            l_move=steps-(i-col);
            
            if((steps-(i-col))>0)
            {
                while(((j-row)<(steps))&&(matrix[j][i]!=4))
                {
                    j+=1;
                }
                tmp=matrix[j][i];
                matrix[j][i]=matrix[row][i];
                matrix[row][i]=4;
                steps-=(row-j);
            
            
            }
        
        
        }
    }
```

please consider that this function is only for this exact situation which is the one causing the problem by changing the places of 4s in a wrong way.

Comment: *... code a board game called "parcheesi"* - damn I feel old right now. I played this on an actual board as a kid.

Comment: @WhozCraig Everything was a board game when we grew up and there were 3 electronic devices in the house (1) the phone mounted on the wall that was property of the phone company, (2) the record player (played 33's, 45's, and 78's) (3) the black and white TV -- the one you watched the Apollo moon landings on. (spoiled in Dallas with 6 channels between VHF and UHF)

Comment: I appreciate and respect your nostalgia fellas but maybe a little bit more focused on the problem here? :D

Comment: Sorry for the digression... I see your board, but where I got stuck is not knowing what you need to move where. Are the big numbers, e.g. `6614,6613` one piece? Additionally, what are the rules for the move (sorry, I was never a big parcheesi player). Is the move only valid to places where there are no big numbers? And the little number, do you have to take them into considerations for scoring, etc.? It also seems like you would want 2 arrays. One `board` arrays holding the scores, etc.. and another `pieces` array that would hold the location of the pieces. Can you clarify?

Comment: 4 digit numbers with 2 in second digits are finishing slots(if four of them(for 1 play) fill up the player wins) the others, which have 1 in second digits are pawns/pieces) moving is along the path which I assigned as 1s and 4s in the matrix. 1s are normal path and 4s are corners which triggers the redirection of the pawns. table is the same as pieces(sorry for inconvenience, forgot to write that). There are no such things as scores in this game. One basically move along the path as much as the dice shows.